# Turn on heat_map parameter in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have switched off heat_map parameter

```
SQL> SHOW PARAMETER heat_map;
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
heat_map                             string      OFF
```

But if I try to make it available I get the following errors:

```
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET heat_map = ON;
ALTER SYSTEM SET heat_map = ON
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02097: parameter cannot be modified because specified value is invalid
ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Heat Map
```

What should I do to enable that parameter?

Comment: Please check your database release version. [Oracle release 12.1 doesn't support heat map in multitenant container database](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-85EF8DD3-B372-4D5A-8941-FD7A0AF9C364.htm#VLDBG14152). [Oracle Release 12.2 support heat map in multitenant container database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/vldbg/ilm-strategy-heatmap-ado.html#GUID-1E510486-2ED8-467A-A5BA-045F4F3AC324).

Comment: I have 12.2 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are shown ORA-00439, you cannot use the specified feature, as it is not enabled.

The first thing to check is to ensure that you are using Oracle Enterprise Edition.
According to [Oracle features - standard edition vs. enterprise edition](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_so_oracle_standard_enterprise_edition.htm) the new heat_map 12c feature is reserved only for users using EE.

Comment: I have EE and tested it dynamically like you and it works perfectly fine.